# function doesn't deduct the first value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following function to get a value from an input and deduct the amount from a fixed value. This happens while the user clicks on an onscreen number pad.

```
function totalFocusOut(elem){
    var subTotal = $(elem).parent().parent().find('.total-due').val();
    var paidAmount = $(elem).val();
    var balanceAmount = parseFloat(subTotal) - parseFloat(paidAmount);
    $('.final-value').html(balanceAmount.toFixed(2));
}
```

The function is triggered bu the following function

```
$('.amount').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ""){
        totalFocusOut($(this));
    }
});
```

When the function is called, it doesn't reduce the first value the user has entered! bt starts to reduce the first value when the second value is entered!

for an example the user first clicks on number 6 button. then number 7 button.
Theoretically the function should first reduce 6 from the amount and then 67 from the amount. The amount is fixed and I save the updated amount in another variable. How can I make the function first reduce the first value and then the second value.

Thank you.

This is the HTML Code

```
<div id="settle-cash">
    <div id="settlement-cash">
        <div id="input-div">
            <label for="table-number">Table No</label>
            <input class="table-number" placeholder="Table Number" type="text"></text>
        </div>
        <div id="input-div">
            <label for="room">Room No</label>
            <input class="room" placeholder="Room Number" type="text"></text>
        </div>
        <div id="input-div">
            <label for="room">No of Guests</label>
            <input class="num-of-guests" placeholder="Number of Guests" type="text"></text>
        </div>
        <div id="input-div">
            <label for="total"">Total</label>
            <input class="total" placeholder="Total" type="text"></text>
        </div>
        <span style="padding-left: 16px">Discount Type:</span>
            <input type="radio" id="dis-percentage" name="discount-type" checked="checked" value="percentage">Percentage</input>
            <input type="radio" id="dis-amount" name="discount-type" value="amount">Amount</input>
        <div id="input-div">
            <label for="discount">Discount</label>
            <input class="discount" placeholder="00.00" type="text"></text>
        </div>
        <div id="input-div">
            <label for="total-due">Total Due</label>
            <input class="total-due" placeholder="Total Due" value="Total Due" type="text"></text>
        </div>
        <div class="balance-section">
            <span class="balance">Balance</span>
            <span class="final-value"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="amount">
        <input class="amount" placeholder="Enter Amount" type="text"></text>

        <!-- Onscreen Number Pad -->
        <div id="number-pad">
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>3</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>5</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>6</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>7</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>8</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>9</span>
            </div>
            <div class="metal linear num-button">
                <span>0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="button del metal linear">
                <span>Del</span>
            </div>
            <div class="button settle metal linear">
                <span>SETTLE</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you post a HTMl snippet as well ?

Comment: What is ".amount" ? Is it not better to attach your handler to your keys and replace blur by click ?

Comment: I've added the html code. I'm not using the physical keyboard. Instead there is an html divs with necessary values. When a user click one, the respective value is added to the input.

Comment: I created this fiddle using your script and a cut down version of your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/UgLaQ/ . Entering something into the text box and then clicking elsewhere looks like it does the right thing. There must be something wrong elsewhere because your function seems fine.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what you were thinking with all those `</text>` tags in there but they are not valid and could potentially be confusing things on some browsers...

Comment: `$(elem).parent().parent()`- why not `$('#settlement-cash')`?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no problem with `JQuery` code and its perfectly fine. Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y9fp2/)

```
$('.amount').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ""){
        totalFocusOut($(this));
    }
});
```

You have incorrect `HTML` and its full of errors, you need correct that.

```
<input class="discount" placeholder="00.00" type="text"></text>
```

should be

```
<input class="discount" placeholder="00.00" type="text"/>
```

And

```
<label for="total"">Total</label>
```

Should be

```
<label for="total">Total</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KvQKW/)**

Your jQuery is ok, it's your html that has problems.

Corrections to apply:
- remove all `</text>` after inputs
- remove value on `<input class="total-due" placeholder="Total Due"...`
- remove extra doublequotes in `<label for="total"">Total</label>`